# Inserting JSON File via POST in Database with PL/SQL

Tags: json, oracle, rest, post, plsql

Im getting following JSON File in a **POST** Request:

```
{
    "Collection":"SA3",
    "Source": "Test",
    "Timestamp": "2013-02-20T11:13:57.7810751+01:00",
    "Inventory": [
        {
            "NUMBER":"234A2",
            "NAME":"ONE",
            "STATUS":"OK"
        },
        {
            "NUMBER":"34A2",
            "NAME":"TWO",
            "STATUS":"NOTOKAY"
        },
        {
            "NUMBER":"9A3DA",
            "NAME":"THREE",
            "STATUS":"DONE"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to **INSERT** it into my database, so that "*Collection*", "*Source*" and "*Timestamp*" are staying in the same row and for every "*Inventory*" is a new row.

In this example it would be like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Collection</th>
    <th>Source</th>
    <th>Timestamp</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SA3</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>2013-02-20T11:13:57.7810751+01:00</td>
    <td>234A2</td>
    <td>ONE</td>
    <td>OK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SA3</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>2013-02-20T11:13:57.7810751+01:00</td>
    <td>34A2</td>
    <td>TWO</td>
    <td>NOTOKAY</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SA3</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>2013-02-20T11:13:57.7810751+01:00</td>
    <td>9A3DA</td>
    <td>THREE</td>
    <td>DONE</td>
  </tr>
 
 
</table>
```

so I need an INSERT Statement in PL/SQL which interates over the Inventory and saves it like above. The inventory column is not created in the database!
Any ideas on how to process here ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oracle version??

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Can you share your table structure? And will you be able to pass this JSON string to a SQL? Can this string be the size of more than 4000 characters?

Comment: i already got it. it was complicated but its working